# Weblogic 12c java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: jsf, myfaces, weblogic12c, mojarra, icefaces-3

There are so many question open around this issue and everyone suggesting the conflict of JSF Libraries with web-logic shared library.

we are migrating our whole application to Weblogic 12c with Spring 4 and hibernate 4.

When deploying I can see one error in log : ClassNotFound Exception which comes when if that jar is not present or if there is conflict in jars and loading the jar which doesn't has that class.

```
Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver': javax.faces.FacesException: org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addVariableResolver(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.faces.FacesException: org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addVariableResolver(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am facing the below issue when accessing the localhost as app is deploying successfully.

```
1.
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

**Anybody have suggestions regarding above issue for weblogic 12c + JSF?**
Interesting thing is our Application working like a charm for spring3 + jsf (icefaces) in weblogic 12c but once I change the jar to spring 4 it starts throwing above JSF issues thats making confusing why for spring 4?

Anyway I got the detailed classloaders from weblogic which shows the loaded class from **shared library** and the **application** but that doesnt helped. If anyone have suggestion if they can see any conflict for JSF library.It's been while I am trying this with so many suggestion but nothing worked.Thanks in advance.

```
**System Classloaders**
Type: sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader
HashCode: 1956433926
Classpath:
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
/C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar

Type: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
HashCode: 345487281
Classpath:

/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_12.1.1.0.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/weblogic.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/webservices.jar
/C:/Oracle12c/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/xqrl.jar
/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/tools.jar

Type: weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader
HashCode: 1277718374
Classpath:


**Application Classloaders**
Type: weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader
HashCode: 929366372
Filter: [antlr.*, antlr.collections.*, antlr.collections.impl.*, antlr.debug.misc.*, com.sun.activation.*, com.sun.istack.*, com.sun.mail.*, com.sun.xml.*, org.apache.commons.*, org.joda.time.*, org.apache.xalan.*, org.apache.xml.*, org.apache.wml.*, org.apache.xerces.*, org.apache.xpath.*, com.ctc.wstx.*, org.slf4j.*, javax.faces.*, com.sun.faces.*, com.bea.faces.*, com.sun.el.*, javax.el.*, javassist.*]
Classpath: empty

Type: weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader
HashCode: 2137066604
Classpath:

**Type: weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader**

HashCode: 1212049573
Filter: []
Classpath: empty
Type: weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader
HashCode: 1604673952
Classpath:


C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\classes
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\FastInfoset-1.2.12.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\_wl_cls_gen.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\acegi-security-1.0.7.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\activation-1.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\activation.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\bcprov-jdk16-140.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\cacauth-2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\camel-core-2.5.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\camel-josql-2.5.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\caps-handshake-3.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\caps2-liquibase-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\caps2domain-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\caps2util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\cloning-1.7.4.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.2.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-digester-2.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-management-1.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\gentlyweb-utils-1.5.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\icefaces-3.2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\icefaces-ace-3.2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\icefaces-compat-3.2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\icepush-3.2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\itext-4.2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\itextpdf-5.0.6.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.9.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jasperreports-ca-4.8.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.el-api-2.2.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.faces-2.2.9.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.inject-1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jax-qname.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-api-2.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-api.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb-impl-2.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxb1-impl.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxp-api.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxws-api-2.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-archive-browsing-5.0.0alpha-200607201-119.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.2.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-bundle-1.18.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\joda-time-2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\joda-time-hibernate-1.3.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\josql-1.5.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\josql-2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\json-20140107.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jsr250-api-1.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jstl-1.2.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\jta-1.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\mail-1.4.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\mail.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\objenesis-1.2.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\opencsv-1.7.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\oro-2.0.8.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\portlet-api-2.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\primefaces-3.4.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\quartz-1.8.4.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\saaj-api-1.3.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\saaj-api.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\saaj-impl.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\serializer.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\servlet.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-aop-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-aspects-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-expression-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jdbc-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jms-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-orm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-tx-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-webmvc-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-ws-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-ws-security-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-xml-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\stax-api-1.0-2.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\3capture-1.0.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\s-beans-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\usertype.core-3.1.0.CR10.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\usertype.jodatime-1.9.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\usertype.spi-3.1.0.CR10.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\wss4j-1.5.8.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xercesImpl.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xml-apis.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xmldsig.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xmlsec-1.4.3.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xmlsec.jar
C:\s-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_4\war\WEB-INF\lib\xws-security-3.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried whatever on web as explained above.But after removing the delegatingVariable resolver from all the faces config xml it resolved my issue. If someone tried everything related with this error please try below it may work for you guys. Good Luck for migration.

```
<variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
```

Comment: I will name first born child after you.